# Number of distinct subgroups in $G$ of the form $aHa^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

If $H$ is a subgroup of finite index in a group $G$, prove that there is only a finite number of distinct subgroups in $G$ of the form $aHa^{-1}$.

I get this question from I.N. Herstein algebra book, and I did this proof. Please review and verify the proof whether it is right or wrong.

Given, $[G:H]=n<\infty$

Let us define $A$ be the set of all distinct left cosets of  $H $ in $G$ and $B$ be the set of all distinct subgroups in $G$ of the form $aHa^{-1}$.

Define a map $f:A\longrightarrow B$ such that $f(aH):=aHa^{-1}$, where $aH\in A.$

Now let us show that the map $f$ is well defined.

If $aH=bH$, then we have $a^{-1}b \in H$. So $aH=bH \Rightarrow aHa^{-1}b=bH \Rightarrow aHa^{-1}=bHb^{-1}.$

Hence we get that $f(aH)=f(bH)$. So the map is well defined. Now it is clear that $f$ is surjective.

So $|A|\geq |B| \Rightarrow n\geq |B|$, since $[G:H]=n$.

Now we get that there is only a finite number of distinct subgroups in the group $G$ of the form $aHa^{-1}$.

Comment: This works. Eventually you will learn about the normalizer of $H$ and learn that the index of the normalizer is the size of your set $B$, and that it always contains $H$, so you will actually get that the number *divides* $n$.

Comment: $G$ acts on all of it's subgroups by conjugation. Then orbit of $H$ is collection of all subgroups conjugate to $H$ and stabilizer of $H$ is it's normallizer. The as sets $|G/stab(G) |=|cl(H) |$ . Now use index of $H $ in $G$.